# JQuery if, first one free logic

Tags: jquery

Ok so I writ some JQuery for updating a price live when a user adds an extra. There is one chunk of code for Booster Seats and one for Child Seats.

Here is one, so you can see exactly what I do:

```
    $('.boostseat').change(function() {
        //sets the var id as the id of the select box
        var id = this.id;
        //sets this as the value of the select box
        numberofboostseat = $(this).val();
        //shows a confirmation message
        $('#boostseatadd-'+id).show();
        //this handles if an item is removed, so that the value doesn't reset
        if (typeof(boosttotal) != "undefined" && boosttotal !== null) {
            price = $("#hiddenprice").val() - boosttotal;
        }else{
            price = $("#hiddenprice").val();
        }
        //number of days you hire it for cariable
        numofdays = "<?php echo $length->days; ?>";
        if (numofdays > 4){
            //alert ("boost if1");
            boostcost = Number(20);

        }else if ((numberofboostseat == 1 || numberofboostseat == 0) && (numberofchildseat == "undefined" || numberofchildseat == 0)){

            //alert ("boost if2");
            boostcost = Number(3) * Number(0);

        }else if (numofdays < 1){
            //alert ("boost if3");
            boostcost = Number(3) * Number(1);

        }else{
            //alert ("boost if4");
            boostcost = Number(3) * Number(numofdays);
        }


        // determines final price
        boosttotal = Number(numberofboostseat) * Number(boostcost);
        //more varaibles 
        newprice = Number(price) + Number(boosttotal);
        //updates hiddden fields
        $("input#hiddenboostprice").val(boosttotal);
        $("input#hiddenboostnum").val(numberofboostseat);
        $("input#hiddenprice").val(newprice);

        oldnumofboost = $("input#hiddenboostnum").val(numberofboostseat);
        //updates the HTML (Live Price Update) as decimal
        $('#'+id).html("&euro;" + newprice.toFixed(2));


    });

});
```

I've tried to comment it a bit to make it clearer. There is another chunk of code like this that handles child seats.

My problem is the the first childseat **OR** booster seat is free.

I tried this:

```
}else if ((numberofboostseat == 1 || numberofboostseat == 0) && (numberofchildseat == "undefined" || numberofchildseat == 0)){
```

As you can see above, the variable boostcost counts the cost of the seats. The other chunk of code, the childseat one also has global variables i can use, similar to these.

Can anyone suggest an if statement that would effectively make the first child OR booster seat free?

Comment: Why do you use `Number(x)` ?

Comment: I just thought it was a safe way to make sure the variables were treated as numbers? I'm no JQuery expert though....

Comment: What does that have to do with jQuery? Anyway, you used it with number literals, not variables.

Comment: Lets say a users buys 3 booster seats, and 5 child seats. Is 1 booster seat free? Or is 1 child seat free?

Comment: 1 of either. If they have 1 child seat and 1 booster seat. only the first one they selected is free. If that makes sense. The rule is the first childseat OR booster seat is free.

Comment: Also you don't need `Number` in there, just use the numbers without the extra declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding `.discount = true` to variables after they have been decremented to prevent the sister varialbe from being decremented as well. This way numberofchildseat or numberofboostseat will be discounted by 1 but never both. As long as `.discounted` has not been set javascript will evaluate it as `false`.

```
   if(!numberofchildseat.discounted && numberofboostseat > 0){
        numberofboostseat--;
        numberofboostseat.discounted = true;
   }
   if(!numberofboostseat.discounted && numberofchildseat > 0){
        numberofchildseat--;
        numberofchildseat.discounded = true;
   }
```

Comment: I'm really sorry if this is a stupid question, but this line numberofchildseat--; does what exactly?

Comment: Its the opposite of `foo++`. Its the same as `numberofchildseat = numberofchildseat - 1;`

Comment: I'm sorry I got pulled away from the computer, I will be implementing it this morning and will let you know.

Comment: I have tried this, although I don't think I am understanding correctly, When you say you are adding .discount = true after the variable is used?